# How to debug a Symfony2 form?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.5

I'm creating a register page to create a new user based on FOSUserBundle.

I go this message on the top f the form every time I submit the new user form:
This value should not be blank.

Apparently this is a global message and it's not linked to a particular field on my form, so I guess it must be related to any other atribute of my User class.

What mechanism Sf2 offers me in order to figure out what's wrong on my form?
I am using Symfony 2.5.0

(I would post more details about my configuration, User class and form... but I really would like to learn how to find this problem on my own)

Thanks in advance, community!

Answer (score 1):

Check out debug toolbar on dev frontend controller, its good debug way for the start

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky error that is hard to track. I was not able to track those type of errors myself, so I searched on Google and SO. I found the answer that explained the problem with my form. It was a validation rule on one of the fields that was not included in the form.

So, in your case that may also be the reason. There is probably a validation rule (most likely `NotBlank`) on a field that is not included in the form. Just try to disable them one by one to find the filed that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try printing your `$request->get('name_of_your_form')`, and after binding it with the form, try printing `$form->getData()`. Should be enough to be clear about what field causes the issue.

Also make note of [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups).

Answer (score 0):

Try printing the form errors out as a string using the `$form->getErrorsAsString()` or the `$form->getErrors()` methods.

Taken from the [source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php#L818)

```
/**
 * Returns a string representation of all form errors (including children errors).
 *
 * This method should only be used to help debug a form.
 *
 * @param int     $level The indentation level (used internally)
 *
 * @return string A string representation of all errors
 *
 * @deprecated Deprecated since version 2.5, to be removed in 3.0. Use
 *             {@link getErrors()} instead and cast the result to a string.
 */
public function getErrorsAsString($level = 0)
{
    return self::indent((string) $this->getErrors(true, false), $level);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should see the error with more description in the logs of the /_profiler even maybe a SQL error which may lead to the root of the problem.